# Does an isometric automorphism of $L_p := L_p (\Omega, \mu, X)$ preserve the support?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $1 \leq p<\infty$, and $(X, |\cdot|)$ be a Banach space. Assume $\varphi$ is an isometric automorphism of $L_p := L_p (\Omega, \mu, E)$. I would like to ask if
$$
[f \in L_p \text{ and } B \in \Sigma] \implies\varphi (f 1_B) = \varphi(f) 1_B.
$$

Informally, does $\varphi$ preserve the support of $f$. If yes, then my second question in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434787/if-h-in-l-q-mu-x-such-that-int-langle-h-f-rangle-mathrm-d-mu) has a positive answer.

Could you elaborate on my question? Thank you so much!

Comment: Doesn't $\varphi$ a translation in $X=\mathbb{R}$ fail that property?

Comment: @Jose27 If your $\varphi$ is $f \mapsto f + \hat f$ for some fixed $\hat f$, then I'm afraid that your $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism...

Comment: No, I meant $f\mapsto f(x+\cdot)$, for some fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jose27 I got it. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: The mapping $\varphi(f)(x)=f(-x)$ gives an isometric isomorphism on $L^p(-1,1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure, and for some fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$ set $\varphi(f)(t):= f(x+t)$. Then $\varphi$ induces an isometric isomorphism on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for any $1\leq p\leq \infty$. However, the desired property $\varphi(f1_B)= \varphi(f)1_B$ is not true for all $f$ and $B$.